# How do I graph data from hidden cells?

Tags: excel

The black area contains a graph, when I hide the data the graph vanishes.

I can still click on the graph and check/uncheck the "Show data in hidden rows and columns" box and I can also check the "Select data source tab" to confirm the data is still selected but it never actually appears.

What's going on and how do I fix this?

With cells hidden:

[image]

With cells un-hidden:

[image]

Confirming data sources still selected:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your chart intersects with the rows or columns being hidden then that is most likely the issue. Right click the chart>Format Chart Area>Size & properties, then selecte something other than "Move and size with cells."

Comment: The chart doesn't intersect them unfortunately. They're below the chart area. I tried it all the same, and no difference.